# loopback storage components -- communicating between two servers

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have two different servers that have storage components managing filesystems.  How do I upload / download between the two?  Loopback docs don't talk about creating a provider listed as another loopback server, only things like amazon and a local file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there's maybe a couple of different ways you could approach this.

First - if you want both servers to have copies of files, you could consider rsync to keep them in sync. You would need to ensure that file names don't overwrite each other (ie, server A has foo.doc and server B), but that could be done by using a UUID in the file name or some other method of uniqueness. If both servers always contain a copy of the file, then your download can happen from either.

Second - or maybe you just want to keep the files on the individual server. If so, you could simply remember where the file was (what server), and your download logic can then return a URL that includes the proper location. This one seems a bit iffy to me, but I'm just putting this out there as an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can exchange data between the two using the [REST connector](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/REST+connector) that is definitively mentionned in the docs.

Basically, it will abstract one server as a datasource for the other, as if it was a cloud storage or local file system.

Comment: I don't believe this is a good solution. From my understanding, the REST connector lets you define a model that can 'proxy' to another API. So while *technically* this could help solve the problem, it would require some complex logic to handle the file sync between both servers. I'll flesh out some thoughts in my own answer.

Comment: @RaymondCamden I don't know about rsync, so you might be right. However I have the feeling that OP is providing enough information for us to answer properly. I believe in most cases if some event happens on server A and you need to propagate to server B, the REST connector will be widely sufficient for that

Comment: I think my issue is - I feel like (and this is a feeling admittedly) that the REST connector is for when the *entire* model is based on another API. In this case, we have a model that may persist just fine, but has a File property that will be problematic since we have 2 servers.